# Truncated Coordinates

Tags: qgis

I have a bunch of TIFF orthophoto in PSAD56 "truncated coordinates":

```
     real        "truncated"
Y  6,400,000       400,000
X    450,000        70,000
```

I don't want to georeference by hand every image, so I tried using a custom coordinate system in QGIS, without success.

I couldn't figure it out the correct parameter to change.

Any thoughts?

Comment: More details please on exactly what you tried and exactly what happened. Screen shots and a text version of your custom coordinate system would help.

Comment: Is `7` in your example a typo? 70,000 is not a truncation of 450,000.